# Getting values of dynamically added controls in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello everyone thank you so much for providing help to me for my previous question as I'm developing application for education domain. In that I take panel control as panel1 and define a few dropdownlist controls in that panel as dropdown1, dropdown2 etc. dynamically in button1 click event and i want to use those controls' values in button2 click event help me for the same.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation.  Could you add to it or give an example?

Answer (score 1):

In button2_Click event, you can get dropdown's values as :

```
DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("dropDownList1");
string dropdown1value = ddl1.SelectedValue;
```

But after second postback, your dynamically added controls will be lost. so you should add them in page's init event not in first button's click event.

Comment: That should read panel1.FindControl("dropDownList1") . If I'm not mistaken, FindControl() only scans first degree child controls.

Comment: @SirDemon : No, Page.FindControl returns controls that are child of another control.

Comment: actually i tried bt it gves an error dat "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."